# QImage segmentation fault upon scaling

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

If the window is continuously resized after setImage has been called at least once, the application randomly produces a segmentation fault. The debugger appears to indicate that the offending line is the call to image.scaled() in canvas.cpp. I am not certain how to trace it further.

*canvas.h*

```
#ifndef CANVAS_H
#define CANVAS_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class Canvas : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Canvas(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);

public slots:
    void setImage(const QImage& image);

private:
    QImage image;
};

#endif // CANVAS_H
```

*canvas.cpp*

```
#include "canvas.h"

Canvas::Canvas(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void Canvas::setImage(const QImage& image) {
    this->image = image;
    this->update();
}

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    QSize size = this->size();

    if (!image.isNull()) {
        QImage scaled = image.scaled(size, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, scaled);
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is currently acquiring images from a camera. It is going to take some time to trim the code down.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm sorry, I wasn't trying to say it was. I was just trying to give a polite heads up.

Comment: You should check if the return scaled image is null before drawing ? Check if size is correct ?

Comment: I think I figured it out. The QImage being used turned out to only be a reference to one created in a context that was being exited.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use QWidget and the paintEvent as virtual protected.